# Any difference between using the default DbContext vs SpecificDbContext as service dependency?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

We use multiple micro-service applications, each with it's own specific DbContext. Few entities are duplicated in all of those contexts by necessity, for example - the `Region` entity. I want to use a single service to perform CRUD on Regions in **all db contexts**. That's why I've used the default `DbContext` as dependency in this service, relying on the IoC container in each micro-service app to provide it's own **specific**, let's call it `ExampleDbContext`. Then I use `Set<Region>` to manipulate the entity.

I get an inconsistent behavior - sometimes it works, while most of the time I get:

> InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A
>   DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is
>   still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second
>   operation is started on this context before a previous operation
>   completed...

From what I can gather the default culprit is simultaneous usage of the same `DbContext` instance. All our methods are `async` so it is certainly possible, but I find it unlikely, since the code that throws is called once on the application start inside the `Program.Main` method. Either way, I am not sure how to confirm it or rule that out.

What I find strange about this is that if I replace `DbContext` with an explicit `ExampleDbContext` this error is no longer thrown. Thus I am lead to believe that there is some difference in how the default `DbContext` is instantiated.

As a further note I think that `ExampleDbContext` is instantiated 3 times, because a breakpoint inside it's `OnConfiguring` method gets hit 3 times.

#### Edit

Turns out using the specific `ExampleDbContext` also throws, however much more rarely.

#### Edit 2

Alright, after another day debugging and commenting out code to pin-point the issue, I can confirm that it was indeed parallel calls to the same `DbContext`instance.

One piece is still still missing from the puzzle:
- Why using `DbContext` instead of `ExampleDbContext` threw more frequently?

Overall I guess the moral of the story is "Take your time to eliminate the obvious cause of the issue". When that's off the tables think about other causes and only then post about asking help.

Comment: Without the *code* it's very hard to understand what you're asking. Using a global  or long-lived DbContext is a bad idea that would have been evident if the code was posted - like connections, contexts are meant to be used only for a short time. It's impossible to say why one or another instance fails more often than the other without the code.

Comment: If you want to put it in a DDD context, a DbContext instance is a UoW. It's not thread-safe because it doesn't make sense for it to be - it contains the data and changes for *one* business operation. All modifications made during that operation will be persisted once a *single* `SaveChangesAsync` call is made. That's why it's a DbContext is typically used inside a `using` block